# Parse all RSS item into c# class

Tags: c#, parsing, rss

What's the best way of parsing the folowing rss feed item into a C# class.

```
<item>
  <fh:FlightHistory FlightHistoryId="189895136" >
     <fh:Airline AirlineCode="EI" Name="Aer Lingus" /> 
  </fh:FlightHistory>
</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use xsd.exe to generate classes from xml/xsd, then use the XmlSerializer to serialize and deserialize class instances in your code.
here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx

Alternatively there's a tool in the Biztalk SDK that allows you to "Paste XML as Serializable type"
http://blogs.msdn.com/mwinkle/archive/2007/05/14/paste-xml-as-serializable-type.aspx

Comment: <Grumble> You beat me by 30 seconds.  Voted you up for good measure.  Good answer.